# I [hadn't wanted]/[didn't want] to marry

Tags: grammaticality

CONTEXT:

John didn't want to marry his English teacher, Cindy, but now that she's done a lot of good things for him, he has changed his mind. He meets his friend, Bob, and says one of the sentences below to him.

SENTENCES:

1. I **hadn't wanted** to marry my English teacher, but she's done so much good for me!
2. I **didn't want** to marry my English teacher, but she's done so much good for me!

QUESTION:

Which of the above sentences should be used in the context given? I'm wondering about the tenses in bold.